# Does php have c++'s std::pair?

Tags: php, c++, associative-array, std-pair

I'd like to make an associative array in PHP where the key is a pair of strings.

At first I was considering concatenating the strings with some sort of unique divider in the middle, and then separating them later, but this seems like a hacky workaround for using a pair.

Consider the following code:

```
$andrew = array('Andrew', 'Rasmussen');
$john = array('John', 'Smith');
$container[$andrew] = 15;
$container[$john] = 12;

$pair = array('Andrew', 'Rasmussen');
if (array_key_exists($pair, $container)) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Obviously this code will not work because you can't use an array as a key in an array in PHP. Is there a *good* way to do something like this without concatenating and then later parsing the strings?

**Edit**

I have a reason for wanting to do this. I have an `array(key=string1,value=array(key=string2,value=occurrences))` and I'm trying to find the top 5 (in terms of occurrences) of string pairs. So I'm basically trying to flatten this into a 1d array and then sort it so I can easily grab the top 5. But to do this I'll need to be able to extract the strings out separately after I've sorted, which can be done with the divider algorithm explained above, but this is not preferable, which is why I'm asking for an alternative.

Comment: Possible? Yes, but it seems a lot more work than just using concatenation and `explode`.

Comment: @paxdiablo what are your thoughts on concat + explode vs. serialize() + unserialize() the array?

Comment: I suspect serialising would be better as you don't need to invent some arbitrary separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize)ing the key?

```
$pair = array('Andrew', 'Rasmussen');
if (array_key_exists( serialize( $pair), $container)) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: Looks like there is an unserialize. I still don't think this is the most elegant method, but it's definitely simple! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of multidimensional arrays (by using it as `$container["Andrew"]["Rasmussen"]` for example).

Also, you can encapsulate all the "hacking" (be it two-dimensional arrays or string concatenation) in your custom ArrayIndexedByPairs class, which could be like the following:

```
interface IArrayIndexedByPairs {
    public Add($key1, $key2, $value);
    public Contains($key1, $key2);
    public Get($key1, $key2);
}
```